# Monolisa font indentation is too small in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, fonts, indentation

I use Monolisa font for programming and I saw that indentation in VSCode is wrong with Monolisa font. I have no problem with other fonts in VSCode such as Menlo, Fira Code and etc but the confusing point for me is that Monolisa font appears correctly in Jetbrains IDEs. I thought that my vscode configuration missing something but no idea where and why? Here is a screenshot from my VSCode settings.json file and the circles with yellow border shows the indentation which has too small width. Any idea why this issue appears and how to fix it?

OS: Mac OS X

[image]

Here you can see my vscode settings.json file with another font (Menlo).

[image]